# angular.js how to tell google to index my site?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexing, seo, google-index

I've an angular.js app. I have followed google's guide for ajax based applications. I've done this:

1. meta tags

`<base href="/">
 <meta name="fragment" content="!">`

2. angular.js config

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');`

3. my html links looks like this(is it wrong?):

`<a ng-href="/#!/login">Login</a>`

4. I submitted sitemap into google search console (x months ago)

I found that I should not use escaped_fragment, is it correct? Am I doing something wrong? It's still not indexing. **Google indexed just homepage.**

When I run fetch as google tool it renders all pages correctly.

Comment: Hi @donthavename, I'm glad it worked. But out of curiosity: what was your issue?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I just had to give out a bounty :) But I don't expect google would start indexing my web anyway.

Comment: Okay, thanks :) But keep me in the loop and maybe answer my questions at the end of my post. I haven't given up on the indexing of your website yet! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found that I should not use escaped_fragment, is it correct?

This is correct, as of this [official announcement](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html).

---

Also there was additional best-practice introduced:

> For optimal rendering and indexing, our new guideline specifies that you should allow Googlebot access to the JavaScript, CSS, and image files that your pages use. This provides you optimal rendering and indexing for your site. Disallowing crawling of Javascript or CSS files in your site’s robots.txt directly harms how well our algorithms render and index your content and can result in suboptimal rankings.

Taken from the [Official Google Webmasters Blog](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2014/10/updating-our-technical-webmaster.html)

---

So, are you allowing Googlebot access to all necessary files?

And how do your URLs look like? Are there also accessible as static HTML? As of the announcements of Google they still recommend the concept of **Progressive enhancement**, so it might be beneficial in your case to also serve static files.

Answer (score 0):

We struggled with the same issue for quite a long period and after decided to use service [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) that makes static cache of you app and provide this content for google and other search crawlers.